# Регистрация ActiveX компонента

Tags: activex, dll

Есть dll с ActiveX компонентом, который должен работать в ие. Как узнать, какие ключи нужно прописать в реестр, чтобы этот компонент корректно зарегистрировался? 
Компонент - activex plugin vlc. Нужно для создания инталляционного файла со своим немного доработанным плагином в installshield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

1. взять чистую машину (то есть такую, куда этот ActiveX не устанавливался),
2. сохранить состояние реестра в файл `reg.exe export before.reg`,
3. зарегистрировать ActiveX dll: `regsvr32 activex.dll`,
4. сохранить состояние реестра в файл `reg.exe export after.reg`,
5. сравнить два файла построчно (например, используя winmerge).

Comment: как вариант)спасибо за ответ!)